# Does the use of YouTube Data API increase size of the Android app?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, storage, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube Data API and the YouTube API to import channels but my app size is very large (50 MB). I have tried to reduce it in every possible way.

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

I have used webp for images. My dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
}
```

I am using volley to fetch JSON data for YouTube channel.

Can somebody guide me how to minimize the size?
This is my project structure:
[image: project structure]

Comment: I tried different solutions and also different devices. on samsung note 5 its size was 50mb but on samsung j7 it was 17Mb and after uploading the apk size was 2Mb. So now I can try on different devices before getting concerned about the size

Comment: If you aren't using a lot of various YouTube Data API v3 endpoints maybe just calling YouTube Data API v3 endpoints URLs might interest you.